# Credits consumed (viewer)

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm using Autodesk Forge IFC viewer to view IFC files. As I saw, it is free service, but somehow my credits are consumed (it goes up to 8 credits per day).
Where I can see why are so much credits consumed (what I did?)? I'm asking because I do same things many days (upload and view IFC files) and credits are consumed only on some days.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using Forge Viewer to view your IFC models, you must translate them from IFC to Forge Viewer format (svf or svf2) by using paid Model Derivative API.

For each IFC->SVF or IFC->SVF2 translation job, it will charge you 0.5 cloud credits. See the pricing table here: https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing

Comment: Thanks, later I also found this so I dropped Forge, it is just too much for me.